# What can I do to connect my 802.11b laptop to 802.11n?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11n

My HP laptop connects with internet through my neighbor wireless and works fine. I have another laptop Toshiba Satellite and I can't connect to internet. I figured out that the wireless radio tape was 802.11n while my Toshiba only supports 802.11b. So I changed the wireles radio tape from 802.11n to 802. 11b only. The HP laptop stills connects and work fine while the Toshiba does not.

What can I do?

Comment: Honestly, 802.11b devices have no business being on 802.11n networks. They slow the entire network down just by being joined to the network as every single other device has to send a special burst to stop the 802.11b device from transmitting before it can transmit any data. (802.11b devices can't recognize the much faster 802.11g/n burst.)

Answer (score 2):

It may be the case that your neighbour has his modem settings to only connect with the 802.11n mode, a lot of the time you can change the setting to use both wireless-n as well as B/G so.. if you can, i would have him change the setting...

Your other option is to buy a cheap usb modem that supports wireless-N.

Answer (score 0):

Easier would be to have friendly neighbor to allow using b/g/n setting in WIRELESS SETTING in his ROUTER rather than current just Wireless-N setting.

Also make sure that he is transmitting 100% radio transmission of his wireless network. Sometime people wrongly play with router and set the wireless radio transmission to less than 50% so to avoid 'onlookers' snooping in their network.

Better would be to buy $10 Wireless-N adapter (microcenter.com).